# Publishing Tableau Dashboard with R scripts to Server

Tags: r, tableau-api

I have built a Dashboard that has multiple calculations using R Scripts and now I want to publish this to our internal Server. I get the following error message:

"This worksheet contains R scripts, which cannot be viewed on the target platform until the administrator configures an Rserve connection."

From what I understand, the administrator has to configure the Rserve, but what about the rest of the installed packages I have in use? Should the administrator install those too and every time I use a new package, I should inform him to install that particular package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the packages on the server that your script will use. Then make sure to start `Rserve` there and connect your Tableau workbook to the server where Rserve is used (using `Rserve connection` in Tableau).

Tableau described the process pretty well:

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/r-implementation-notes